# MYSQL : How to calculate the moving average of each data?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I check the 3 sums (moving average) of each item?

I cannot calculate each item using the following results.

```
Original data : 
scdate              | value  |
--------------------|--------|
2021-11-10 17:00:00 | 1943.98|
2021-11-10 17:00:18 | 1957.13|
2021-11-10 17:00:36 | 1953.94|
2021-11-10 17:00:54 | 1946.28|
2021-11-10 17:01:12 | 1960.29|
2021-11-10 17:01:29 | 1950.39|
2021-11-10 17:01:47 | 1942.62|
2021-11-10 17:02:05 | 1954.64|
2021-11-10 17:02:23 | 1958.21|
2021-11-10 17:02:41 | 1950.26|
2021-11-10 17:02:58 | 1945.33|
2021-11-10 17:03:16 | 1960.35|
```

use mysql

```
   SELECT  scdate,value1,value2,avg(tt.value1) as avg_v1,avg(tt.value2) as avg_v2 ,avg(tt.value2) as avg_v FROM
(
SELECT t.scdate,t.value1,t.value2,(@rownum := @rownum + 1) - 1 AS rownum FROM (SELECT @rownum := 0) 
r,scantech_data t 
ORDER BY  scdate asc
) tt
WHERE scdate >= '2021-11-10 17:00:00' and  scdate <='2021-11-10 17:10:00'
GROUP BY tt.rownum - tt.rownum % 3
order by scdate
```

---

```
***Wrong result

 scdate              |  value1 |  value2 |  avg1   |  avg2   |
 --------------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
 2021/11/10 17:00:00 | 1943.98 | 1942.22 | 1951.68 | 1950.93 |
 2021/11/10 17:00:54 | 1946.28 | 1946.15 | 1952.32 | 1951.55 |
 2021/11/10 17:01:47 | 1942.62 | 1943.05 | 1951.82 | 1952.49 |
 2021/11/10 17:02:41 | 1950.26 | 1949.86 | 1951.98 | 1951.96 |
```

How can I get the following results ??

How should i modify ??

```
***Correct result

 scdate              | value   |  value2 |  avg_v1  | avg_v2  |
 --------------------|---------|---------|----------|---------|
 2021/11/10 17:00:00 | 1943.98 | 1942.22 | 1951.68  | 1950.93 |
 2021/11/10 17:00:18 | 1957.13 | 1957.25 | 1952.45  | 1952.24 |
 2021/11/10 17:00:36 | 1953.94 | 1953.32 | 1953.50  | 1952.78 |
 2021/11/10 17:00:54 | 1946.28 | 1946.15 | 1952.32  | 1951.56 |
 2021/11/10 17:01:12 | 1960.29 | 1958.88 | 1951.10  | 1950.52 |
 2021/11/10 17:01:29 | 1950.39 | 1949.64 | 1949.22  | 1949.50 |
 2021/11/10 17:01:47 | 1942.62 | 1943.05 | 1951.82  | 1952.49 |
 2021/11/10 17:02:05 | 1954.64 | 1955.81 | 1954.37  | 1954.76 |
 2021/11/10 17:02:23 | 1958.21 | 1958.62 | 1951.27  | 1951.24 |
 2021/11/10 17:02:41 | 1950.26 | 1949.86 | 1951.98  | 1951.97 |
 2021/11/10 17:02:58 | 1945.33 | 1945.25 | 1952.84  | 1953.02 |
 2021/11/10 17:03:16 | 1960.35 | 1960.79 | 1960.35  | 1960.79 |
```

ps :
2021-11-10 17:00:00  value1 :  1943.98  avg1 : 1951.68

(1943.98 + 1957.13 + 1953.94 ) / 3 = 1951.68

use version : MySql 5.1.47

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 5.1.47 is a client version, not your server version.  what does `select version();` show?

Comment: @ysth
mysql> select version();
    +------------------+
    | version()        |
    +------------------+
    | 5.1.47-community |
    +------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: wow, that is very very old and will have so many known security bugs

Comment: It's very nice of you!
I should update it ~~~

Answer (score 0):

[Link to view windows features](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/)

```
SELECT scdate, value,
SUM(value) 
OVER 
(PARTITION BY scdate ORDER BY scdate ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW  AND 3 FOLLOWING)
FROM test;
```

approximate query

Comment: my  version : MySql 5.1.47
this MySQL Functions not support ...

Comment: version can be updated

Comment: It's very nice of you!I should update it